# Print City Map in High Resolution with TileMill (OSM Data)

Tags: openstreetmap, printing, tilemill, resolution

I'm rather beginner in Print Map and GIS. I'd like to print the map of my little city using the data in OpenStreetMap. I've got an environment(local) with OSM DataBase  and I'm using TileMill to create StyleSheet and export data. 
My problem is the definition of export. As you know, in TileMill you can export data in SVG, PDF and XML, and you can define just the BBox. The Resolution seems hard coded and set to 72dpi. To increase the quality and the details of export image I have to reduce the BBox (since to have a higher zoom level).

Since I need to print a classic city map (the paper size is, more or less, 80cm X 50cm and the city area 2km X 1km), does anybody have an idea for print it with a good resolution?

If i set 300 dpi as resolution, I'll solve my issue, but maybe I can't.
As I said before, I have a local environment, but perhaps someone knows some other ways.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try SVG export? SVG is vector format and may be rasterized with any resolution after being exported.

Answer (score 0):

Two answers possible:

Or you follow this steps by steps guide straight from the Mapbox Blog: [here](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/print-maps-tilemill-boulder-colorado/)

Or you dig on how to use the *Print Composer* in **Qgis**.

Answer (score 0):

you should give maperitive a try. Its free software for windows (but closed code). with a very friendly and helpful community - and a reasonable good documentation of the software:

maperitve homepage with download:
http://maperitive.net/

two minutes intro to maperitve:
http://maperitive.net/docs/TwoMinutesIntro.html

maperitve users group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/maperitive

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, yes, Tilemill does not [really support static maps](https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill/issues/1935), and its native resolution is web resolution – as you have noticed.

The basic workaround is:

- print more pixels (which makes everything smaller)
- increase the map *Scale Factor* (which makes everything bigger)

[image]

I find you have to experiment a bit, but the process is basically:

1. Export an image of the right size and detail;
2. Multiply the number of pixels in both directions by 4 (dpi now around 280)
3. Increase the scale factor by 4